# CheckList using Tix in python

Tags: python, tix

Is there any way to customize the look of the CheckList widget? Or any widget using Tix?
I initially started using Tkinter for everything, but this CheckList would really help.  I just need to know how to customize the look.

Comment: Have you looked into using `ttk` instead of `tix`? It seems to be a more modern set of widgets, with a more native styling. http://docs.python.org/library/ttk.html

Comment: I have looked into ttk and am open to using it.  ttk has a treeview, but i need checkboxes next to the items.